# Oracle APEX manualy upload file

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a problem with manually uploading the file from the SQL query. The file is sent to the database, but after re-filling the form (for the first time it only sends the completed form data). The file remains visible in the session and is as if stored until the next form filling. I know I can do this as Automatic Query Submission (DML) but I need to do it manually (I have a query that imports data into several tables at once)

```
DECLARE
l_blob BLOB;
l_filename VARCHAR2 (200);
l_mime_type VARCHAR2 (200);
l_token VARCHAR2 (32000);

BEGIN
l_filename := :P8_ATTACH;
l_mime_type := 'application/pdf');
DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_blob, FALSE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);

FOR i IN 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.COUNT
LOOP
l_token := wwv_flow.g_f01 (i);

IF LENGTH (l_token) > 0
THEN
DBMS_LOB.append
(dest_lob => l_blob,
src_lob => to_blob
(UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode
(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (l_token)
)
)
);
END IF;
END LOOP;

IF DBMS_LOB.getlength (l_blob) IS NOT NULL
THEN
UPDATE REZERV
SET ATTACH = l_blob,
MIMETYPE = l_mime_type,
FILENAME = l_filename
WHERE ID = :P8_ID;


END IF;

END;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered
'Purge file at' = 'End of request'
or
'Source -> Used' = 'Always replacing session state'